# Django docker doesn't hot reload for the updates in some folders somehow

Tags: django, docker, hot-reload

I run Django docker and hot reload works normally in most folders.
But it doesn't work in some folders.
Here are my basic folder structure.

whaleserver (Django project)

- api (app)

  - migrations
  - ...
  - v1
  - v2
  - ..

Any change inside v1 triggers hotreload but v2 change doesn't somehow.
Need help to diagnose this.

I already researched but couldn't find proper solution for this.
Much appreciated if anyone can give me helpful suggestion on it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does v2 contain? Can you add an example and describe the changes you make?

Comment: v2 is just folder containers views, serializers etc like v1. I manage views and serializers etc by these folder structure to split legacy version and new one. As a simple test, I just try change return value of any function inside v1 folder and it always trigger docker hot reload. But V2 doesn't. No difference between v1 and v2 in terms of Django context. It is just sub folders of same app.

Comment: Are the views/urls in v2 imported in your main url config? If the files are not imported then changes to them won't be detected

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. v1 and v2 has its own urls.py and they are all finally imported in urls.py of main app with settings.py

Comment: Anyone can help this?